# Using multiple radio buttons to toggle slide out windows

Tags: html, css

Trying to possibly use radio buttons to create multiple buttons down the left side of the page that effect slide out window/windows on the right.

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}

label
{
background:red;
background-size:100%;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
top:-50px;
left:10px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 60px 0 10px 0;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}


div1
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:100%;
background: white;
width: 35%;
height: 100%;
line-height: 20px;
text-align:left;
color: black;
margin:20px 20px 20px 20px:
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
Z-index:1;
overflow:scroll;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div1 
{
background:grey;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:65%;
overflow:scroll;
}


label:hover
{
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Effect I am looking for where the red block is a button and the text window slides in and out

http://jsfiddle.net/bKaxg/215/

Trick is I need other buttons to return the last slide out window off screen before the next window is toggled.

Similar to this but don't want horizontal tabs http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/ or the limited location of the content area.

Other solutions welcome as long as they are CSS/HTML based.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. I made an example with 2 radio button's. The trick is to set a transition-delay to the div that is currently closed. I will explain my code with comments.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="one">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="two">

<label for="one">slider one</label>
<label for="two">slider two</label>

<div class="slider slider_one">one</div>
<div class="slider slider_two">two</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden; /* you can change this, just for the example */
}

input {
    position:absolute; /* move the checkbox from the field since we can't style them */
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
}

label {
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* use labels instead, linked to the checkboxes */
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.slider {
    position:absolute; /* we move the content sliders from the field */
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    right:-400px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* transition of 1 second */
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

#one:not(:checked) ~ .slider_two, #two:not(:checked) ~ .slider_one  {
    -webkit-transition-delay:1s; /* this is where the magic happens, the currently closed div get's a 1 second delay, the same duration as the animation. This will make sure that the the div will close first and that the second div will open after that. */
    -moz-transition-delay:1s;
    transition-delay:1s;
}

#one:checked ~ .slider_one,
#two:checked ~ .slider_two {
    right:0; /* on click on a label, radio button get's checked and we move the slider out */
}
```

This solution has one flaw! The first transition will also have a delay of 1 second, therefor it will seem like the first animation has a delay.

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/kWQ3c/1/

hope this helps you out!

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kWQ3c/2/

Comment: Thanks for the response.
That is the effect i am going for but not quite all I need. 
I was looking for the buttons to be vertically aligned not horizontal and also the content section (Slider) to be different for different buttons (Say one slides out from the top or bottom or is a different size) but it still must return the previous slider off screen.

Comment: @user2677116 Check my new fiddle, maybe this is more what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/kWQ3c/2/